# Sails + passport + Basic Authentication

Tags: javascript, sails.js, basic-authentication, passport.js

in passport js, basic strategy, the following code sample provides a function for verifying the identity of a user.

```
passport.use(new BasicStrategy(
  function(userid, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ username: userid }, function (err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) { return done(null, false); }
      if (!user.verifyPassword(password)) { return done(null, false); }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));
```

Question is where (which file) in a Sails application should this code be placed? I suppose same applies for a custom verification function?

Answer (score 0):

1. create AuthController under controllers directory
2. then write code to make passport handle login process

   ```
   login: function(req, res) {

   passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
       if ((err) || (!user)) {
           return res.send({
               message: info.message,
               user: user
           });
       }
       req.logIn(user, function(err) {
           if (err) res.send(err);
           return res.send({
               message: info.message,
               user: user
           });
       });

   })(req, res);
   ```
3. this line `passport.authenticate('local'` will read configuration from passport.js inside config.js which will be like this :-

   passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
       usernameField: 'email',
       passwordField: 'password'
     },
     function(email, password, done) {

   ```
   User.findOne({ email: email }, function (err, user) {
     if (err) { return done(err); }
     if (!user) {
       return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect email.' });
     }

     bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function (err, res) {
         if (!res)
           return done(null, false, {
             message: 'Invalid Password'
           });
         var returnUser = {
           email: user.email,
           createdAt: user.createdAt,
           id: user.id
         };
         return done(null, returnUser, {
           message: 'Logged In Successfully'
         });
       });
   });
   ```
4. add these line into  route.js :-   `'post /login': 'AuthController.login'`